# Remove duplicate (combination of 2 columns) values in a row

Tags: sql, oracle, vertica

I have a requirement to remove duplicate values present in a row.
like :

```
C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5 | C6
----------------------------
1  | 2  |  1 | 2  | 1  | 3
1  | 2  |  1 | 3  | 1  | 4
1  |NULL|  1 |NULL| 1  |NULL
```

OUTPUT of the query should be:

```
C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5 | C6
----------------------------
1  | 2  |  1 | 3  |NULL|NULL
1  | 2  |  1 | 3  | 1  | 4
1  |NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL
```

As you can see combination of 2 columns should be unique in a row.

in Row 1:
combination of 1/2 is duplicate so its removed and 1/3 is in c5/c6 is moved to c3/c4

in Row 2:
there is no duplicate in the combination of 1/2 , 1/3, 1/4  so no change in the result

in Row 3:
All the 3 combinations are same like 1/NULL is present in all the combinations so c3 to c6 is set to null.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is not very precise. What exactly do you need? Your examples can be interpreted in many ways and your description kind of contradicts itself. "remove duplicate values present in a row" is not the same as "combination of 2 columns should be unique in a row". Also, which combinations should be unique?

Comment: Updated the question!!

Comment: does all the columns are coming from the same table? SHow the SQL of your query

Comment: Yes , all columns are in the same table

Comment: I don't understand what your output is and I dont see a match between that output and that sentence "combination of 2 columns should be unique in a row." You should really add much more details.

Comment: Why did the value for C4 change from 2 to 3 in the first row?

Comment: Does it clarify the question?

Comment: What I think you aren't explaining is that you are treating these columns in pairs. (c1,c2), (c3, c4), (c5, c6) and you are looking to remove duplicate pairs. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a more clever way... but you could convert them to pairs, distinct (union in this case does that), then pivot back.

```
with pairs as (
    select id, c1 as x, c2 as y from mytable
    union
    select id, c3, c4 from mytable
    union 
    select id, c5, c6 from mytable
)
select id, 
       max(decode(rn,1,x)) c1,
       max(decode(rn,1,y)) c2,
       max(decode(rn,2,x)) c3,
       max(decode(rn,2,y)) c4,
       max(decode(rn,3,x)) c5,
       max(decode(rn,3,y)) c6
from (
    select id, x, y, row_number() over (partition by id) rn
    from pairs
) as foo
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works - data included for testing, but might take some time to understand

A tip: un-comment the code snippets under the -- debug lines, copy the script until just these code snippets and paste this part into an SQL prompt to test the intermediate results.

The principle is get a row identifier to "remember" the rows; then to vertically pivot - not 3 columns to one, but 6 columns to 3 pairs of columns; then, use DISTINCT to de-dupe; then get an index within the row identifier of the de-duped intermediate rows; then use that index to pivot horizontally again.

Like so:

```
WITH
input(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6) AS (
          SELECT 1,        2,1,        2,1,        3
UNION ALL SELECT 1,        2,1,        3,1,        4
UNION ALL SELECT 1,NULL::INT,1,NULL::INT,1,NULL::INT
)
,
-- need rowid
input_with_rowid AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS rowid, * FROM input
)
,
-- three groupy of 2 columns, so pivot using 3 indexes
idx3(idx) AS (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3)
,
-- pivot vertically, two columns at a time and de-dupe
pivot_pair AS (
SELECT DISTINCT
  rowid
, CASE idx 
    WHEN 1 THEN c1
    WHEN 2 THEN c3
    WHEN 3 THEN c5
  END AS c1
, 
  CASE idx 
    WHEN 1 THEN c2
    WHEN 2 THEN c4
    WHEN 3 THEN c6
  END AS c2
FROM input_with_rowid CROSS JOIN idx3
)
-- debug
-- SELECT * FROM pivot_pair ORDER BY rowid;
,
-- add sequence per rowid
pivot_pair_with_seq AS (
SELECT
  rowid
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY rowid) AS seq
, c1
, c2
FROM pivot_pair
)
-- debug
-- SELECT * FROM pivot_pair_with_seq;

SELECT
  rowid
, MAX(CASE seq WHEN 1 THEN c1 END) AS c1
, MAX(CASE seq WHEN 1 THEN c2 END) AS c2
, MAX(CASE seq WHEN 2 THEN c1 END) AS c3
, MAX(CASE seq WHEN 2 THEN c2 END) AS c4
, MAX(CASE seq WHEN 3 THEN c1 END) AS c5
, MAX(CASE seq WHEN 3 THEN c2 END) AS c6
FROM pivot_pair_with_seq
GROUP BY rowid
ORDER BY rowid
;

rowid|c1|c2|c3|c4|c5|c6
    1| 1| 2| 1| 3|- |-
    2| 1| 2| 1| 3| 1| 4
    3| 1|- |- |- |- |-
```

Answer (score 0):

Using marcothesane's idea with pivot/unpivot operators. Easier to maintain if more input columns should be deduplicated. This maintains the order of source data (column pairs) - whereas marcothesane's solution might reorder column pairs depening on input data. Also it is a little slower than marcothesane's. It works only in 11R1 and up.

```
WITH
input(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6) AS (
          SELECT 1,        2,1,        2,1,        3 from dual
UNION ALL SELECT 1,        2,1,        3,1,        4 from dual
UNION ALL SELECT 1,NULL ,1,NULL ,1,NULL   from dual
)
,
-- need rowid
input_with_rowid AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by 1) AS row_id, input.* FROM input
),
unpivoted_pairs as
(
  select row_id, tuple_idx, val1, val2, row_number() over (partition by row_id, val1, val2 order by tuple_idx) as keep_first
  from input_with_rowid
  UnPivot include nulls(
          (val1, val2)  --measure 
                for tuple_idx in ((c1,c2) as 1,
                                  (c3,c4) as 2,
                                  (c5,c6) as 3)
          )
)
select row_id, 
       t1_val1 as c1,
       t1_val2 as c2,
       t2_val1 as c3,
       t2_val2 as c4,
       t3_val1 as c5,
       t3_val2 as c6
from (
      select row_id,  
             val1, val2, row_number() over (partition by row_id order by tuple_idx) as tuple_order
      from unpivoted_pairs
      where keep_first = 1
      )
pivot (sum(val1) as val1, sum(val2) as val2
       for tuple_order in ('1' as t1, '2' as t2, '3' as t3)
       )
```